# About basis of Hilbert modular forms

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

I think this is very, very simple and obvious, but I can not understand the problem. **I guess it is just a typo.**

In this context, $F$ is a real quadratic field, and $x\mapsto x'$ stands for the conjugate of $x$ in $F$. At the beginning of the second chapter of the book "The 1−2−3 of Modular Forms", a lemma is stated about the Imaginary part of $z=(z_1, z_2)$ (Note that $a', b', c', d'$ are conjugates of $a, b, c, d$):

[image]

The lemma says $\mathfrak{I}(\gamma(z))= \Big(\dfrac{\mathfrak{I}(z_1)}{|N(cz+d)|^2}, \dfrac{\mathfrak{I}(z_2)}{|N(cz+d)|^2}\Big)$, but **my calculations say something else**:

$$\mathfrak{I}(\gamma(z))
=\Big(\mathfrak{I}(\gamma(z_1)), \mathfrak{I}(\gamma'(z_2))\Big)
=\Big(\frac{\mathfrak{I}(z_1)}{|cz_1+d|^2}, \frac{\mathfrak{I}(z_2)}{|c'z_2+d'|^2}\Big),$$

for example for the first coordinate, we multiply the numerator and the denominator by $c\bar{z_1}+d=\overline{cz_1+d}$. Then

$$\mathfrak{I}(\gamma(z_1))=\frac{az_1+b}{cz_1+d}=\frac{az_1+b}{cz_1+d} \times \frac{c\bar{z_1}+d}{\overline{cz_1+d}} =\frac{(ac|z_1|^2+bd)+(adz_1+bc\bar{z_1})}{|cz_1+d|^2}=\frac{(ac|z_1|^2+bd)+(adx_1+bcx_1)+i(ad-bc)y_1)}{|cz_1+d|^2},$$

and note that the first two parentheses in the numerator of the last fraction are real, also $ad-bc=1$, and $\mathfrak{I}(z_1)=y_1$, and we are done.

I can not understand where is the problem? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @prets It is enough to write $z_i=x_i+iy_i$. For example for the first coordinate, we multiply the numerator and the denominator by $c\bar{z_1}+d$ (note that it is equal to the complex conjugate of $cz_1+d$). Then the numerator would be $(ac|z_1|^2+bd)+(adz_1+bc\bar{z_1})$. Clearly the first paranthese is real. Now write $z_1=x_1+iy_1$, then the second paranthese would be $adx_1+bcx_1+i(ad-bc)y_1$, so we can conclude that the imaginary part is equal to $\dfrac{(ad-bc)y_1}{|cz_1+d|^2}=(ad-bc)\dfrac{\mathfrak{I}(z_1)}{|cz_1+d|^2}$, but notice that $ad-bc=1$

Comment: Your calculations are good. I think they're just taking $\Im(z) = \Im (z_1, z_2) := \Im(z_1)\Im(z_2)$ by definition. Which unhelpfully they don't tell you. (I guess so that $\Im(z)$ is always a number, not a tuple.)

Comment: See also [this paper](https://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/media/algebra/homepages/li/HilbMod.pdf) where the author seems to do the same thing after the first display on page 2, working with products of componentwise imaginary parts.

Comment: @prets The purpose of this statement is to show that this action is well-defined, i.e $\gamma(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$. Actually, this relation and it's analogous [$\mathfrak{I}(\gamma(z))=\dfrac{\mathfrak{I}(z)}{|cz+d|^2}$] do not matter, and their purpose is just to show that the action is well-defined. If we consider the product of the imaginary parts, then we can not conclude $\gamma(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I agree, but it still seems to be what the notation means. That said, since we know $\Im(z_1), \Im(z_2) > 0$, we really can conclude this from looking at that product.